# How can I insert a value into a table where the column contains special character?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to insert a record into an MsSql data table. It is an easy thing, but the target table contains special naming columns like:
<"mz,x",int>
Unfortunately I cannot rename the column, because I do not own the database.
My code fails with exception:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection())
{
            SqlCommand cmd = CreateNewCmd(conn);
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(@mz,x)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@mz,x", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The exception is:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@mz".

The problem is of course with the comma. How could I protect the command in my sql, or how can I insert a simple record into this table?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you trying to name your parameter `@mz,x`? You aren't specifying column names anywhere in your code.

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO test ([<"mz,x",int>]) VALUES(@mz)`

Comment: You are confusing column names and parameter names.

Comment: John, You are right! Not necessary to name the parameters after the column name. If 1 use normal parameter name, than the system can insert it into the table.

Comment: You are right Guy! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the [SQL syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) you try to use but you can write:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection())
{
  var cmd = CreateNewCmd(conn);
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?,?)";
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@value3", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Supposing that the table `test` has 3 columns for the sample, we add a row with all the cells so we don't need to name the columns as you tried to do in the *values* predicate that should be the parameter name (here we use `?` instead to avoid some incompatibilities).

Ideally the request should be:

```
INSERT INTO test (column1Name, column2Name, column3Name) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

You can name the parameters if the database support that and there is no problem between it and the ADO.NET provider:

```
INSERT INTO test (column1Name, column2Name, column3Name) VALUES (@value1, @value2, @value3)
```

If you got an exception, use `?` like the .NET Framework does.

For your column *special name*, I don't know but you may try the @AnkitDas answer.

Comment: Please do not suggest writing an insert statement without specifying columns list :(

Comment: @Arvo Not false... I wrote this answer without knowing anything about the structure and especially to indicate the problem of naming the column in place of the value. Not very clearly mentioned it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to wrap your column name in square brackets: [mz,x]

And i dont think you need to declare a variable as "@mz,x". Instead just simply declare it as mz for using it in the C# code.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection())
{
            SqlCommand cmd = CreateNewCmd(conn);
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test([mz,x]) VALUES(@mz)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@mz", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```